# left-click revert - rectangle, mouseClickedEvent

Tags: java

I've created a basic Java program that creates a rectangle on startup and every time it is clicked, the rectangle grows and changes to a different (random) color.  here's my code:

```
package rectPAK;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DisplayRect {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setBounds(0,0,1000,1000);
    window.getContentPane().add(new MyCanvas());
    window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and then myCanvas is this:

```
package rectPAK;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class MyCanvas extends JComponent{
int W = 100;
int H = 100;
int r;
int g;
int b;
int trans;
int maxRandNum = 255;
int xPoint;
int yPoint;


public MyCanvas() {
    this.addMouseListener(m);
    this.addMouseMotionListener(ml);
}

Random rand = new Random();

MouseListener m = new MouseListener() {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        W = W + 20;
        H = H + 20;
        r = rand.nextInt(maxRandNum);
        g = rand.nextInt(maxRandNum);
        b = rand.nextInt(maxRandNum);
        trans = rand.nextInt(maxRandNum);

        repaint();

    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {


    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

};

MouseMotionListener ml = new MouseMotionListener() {

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

        Point p = e.getLocationOnScreen();
        xPoint = p.x;
        yPoint = p.y;

        repaint();

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

};

public void paint(Graphics gr) {
    gr.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    gr.drawRect(xPoint, yPoint, W, H);
    gr.setColor(new Color(r,g,b,trans));
    gr.fillRect(xPoint, yPoint, W, H);
}

}
```

now my question is this: how do i make it so that when i right-click on the rectangle, it reverts to the previous size and color? i Know it's a lot to ask, but i cant find anything about it...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use a set of "previous" variables (eg previousX, previousY, previousR, etc) to store the old info before every update, and create a right click event to call a method like your paint method to set the object's variables to previousX, previousY, etc.

Comment: okay here's my code now:
`if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1){
   ;
   W = W + 20;
   H = H + 20;
   previousH = H - 20;
   previousW = W - 20;
   r = rand.nextInt(maxRandNum);
   g = rand.nextInt(maxRandNum);
   b = rand.nextInt(maxRandNum);
   trans = rand.nextInt(maxRandNum);
   previousR = r;
   previousG = g;
   previousB = b;
   previousTrans = trans;
   repaint();
   }
   

   else if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3){
    ;
    r = previousR;
    g = previousG;
    b = previousB;
    trans = previousTrans;
    W = previousW;
    H = previousH;
    repaint();
   }
  }`
@dharini

Comment: In MouseEvent.BUTTON1, put all of this first:
prevH = H;
prevW = W;
prevR = R;
etc.
before you start making new random assignments. I think your current code will set prevR,G,B,and Trans to the new random assignments. The right click method looks good. Investigate D.C.'s stack suggestion above for storing previous values if you want to be able to dig back through multiple layers of history, not just the last step.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you generate a random number, store it as the previous instance. This way you will be able to go back one step. If you want to go back all the way to the first one, then you should store each created rectangle's parameters in an stack of sorts, where you could pop out each previous stage.

Once that is done you should create a method for handling right clicks, and in that method, you should set the rectangles parameters to the previous value.

Comment: now how would i make a 'stack of sorts'? i think that would be the way tto go but i don't know exactly what you mean by that

Comment: Tiberius, there are many inbuilt data types in Java which you could use for this. ArrayLists for one..it has many inbuilt functions which you can use..http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html Check the java doc